# How do I ag search into a specific set of folders using the -G option?

Tags: ag

How do I ag search into a specific set of folders using the -G option?

Here's an example where I use `-G routes`, but it's picking up another result from another folder, because `routes` is still in the path.  Yet if I try `-G ^routes`, it doesn't seem like the regex is taking?

[image]

On that note, Atom has a nice path searching syntax which lets me do things like `app,routes,!storage` (search in app and routes folders, but ignore storage folder).  Since I've switched to vim, I'm finding it hard to get a searching workflow down with ack/ag.  Anyone have any tips for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you'd really like to try this plugin `https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim`. It will (among other things) run your ag search and present the result in a fuzzyfinder. Then you'll have the very same feature you mention in atom by running `:Ag middleware` followed by(in the fzf window) `'app/ 'routes/ !storage/'`.

about the use of regex for the file pattern, you'll need to quote your regex

```
ag -G '^routes' middleware
```

that being said, the '^...' doesn't work as intended here on my computer either, although '\b' does. I started using ripgrep instead of the-silver-searcher not so much because it's faster but rather because it has a better documentation, maybe you'd like to give it a try. `rg -g` will take a glob which is easier to understand than the "FILEPATTERN" mentioned in the ag man page

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sudavid4!  I already use and love fzf.vim, but prefer :Ack (to fzf.vim's :Ag) because of it's integration with the quickfix window, which can make larger refactors easier.  I wonder why the `^` regex doesn't work though?

Comment: fzf has a select-all that populates the quickfix though. If you wish to search->filter results -> populate quickfix with a subset of the original results.
It's alt+a by default which doesn't work well on mac so I've changed it for my use, this is the file/line you'd need to change if alt+a doesn't work for you(https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/autoload/fzf/vim.vim#L687)

Comment: Oooo, I was looking into populating quickfix a bit ago but couldn't figure it out.  I'll take another look thanks!

Comment: Using the fzf fuzzy search after is definitely helpful, but sometimes too fuzzy in certain scenarios it seems.  If I could just figure out why `^` regex won't work with `-G`.  It would also make running previous searches a bit easier, as all the params would be in vim's command history.

Comment: You should look more into [fzf extended-search](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#search-syntax). E.g:`^routers` inside the fzf window will filter out everything that doesn't start with routers. `^routers 'boo` say 'must start with routers and have an exact match boo'. `^routers 'boo !maa faa` say 'start with routers, have an exact boo match, not have an exact match maa and fuzzy search faa`. It's actually stronger than hardcoding this in your ag search. If you still really want it in your search, seriously, try the ripgrep. It's faster and better documented than ag.

Comment: Nice, the fzf extended-search syntax workflow is .  I'll take a look at ripgrep as well.  Before I mark this as answered (sorry for holding it hostage ), how are you populating your quickfix with fzf's `:Ag` results?  After googleing a while, I finally figured out how to get this stuff in quickfix with https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/185#issuecomment-322120216 , but I can't hit enter on a quickfix item to open that result in a buffer.  Have you figured this out?

Comment: Oh nevermind!  I had a `<CR>` mapping that was messing with my quickfix window.  Thank you so much again for your ideas!